# Better way to have static class / method access a gameObject variable from several scripts away?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

TLDR: How can I have a script that inherits from a `public abstract class` have access to an often changing Enemy `gameObject` variable (so it can't be static) without passing it through several other scripts first?

In my game, I have a battle system where a different "Battle Event" gets loaded for each battle. Each "Battle Event" gets its own script, and each of those events inherits from the same `BattleEvent` parent (which is `public abstract`).

The code structure basically goes:

1. `BattleSystem` (main brain of battles which holds the Enemy
   gameObject) ->
2. `BattleEventsManager` (handles both which `BattleEvent` to load, and which methods to run on that BattleEvent) ->
3. a random `BattleEvent` (`BattleEventOne` or `BattleEventTwo` etc)

```cs
public class BattleSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    BattleEventsManager battleEventsManager;
    public Enemy currentEnemy;

    // the Enemy data is passed when the battle starts
    public void Start(Enemy enemyToLoad)
    {
        battleEventsManager = GetComponent<BattleEventsManager>();
        currentEnemy = enemyToLoad;
    }


    public void BeginPlayerTurn()
    {
        battleEventsManager.SetupEvent(currentEnemy);
    }
}
```

```cs
public class BattleEventsManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    BattleEvent currentBattleEvent;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // define this battleEvent
        currentBattleEvent = GetComponent<BattleEventOne>();
    }


    public void SetupEvent(Enemy currentEnemy)
    {
        // start the battleEvent with its Setup function
        currentBattleEvent.Setup(currentEnemy);

    }
}
```

```cs
// inherits from `BattleEvent` parent class, shown below
public class BattleEventOne : BattleEvent
{
    // override the method from the parent
    public override void Setup(Enemy currentEnemy) {

       // we can now use the data we need in `currentEnemy`
       // all I wanted was to get access to `BattleSystem.currentEnemy`
       // but i had to pass it down all the way here. Is there a better way?

    }
}
```

```cs
// parent of all `BattleEvents`
public abstract class BattleEvent : MonoBehaviour
{
    public abstract void Setup(Enemy currentEnemy);
} // end BattleEvent class
```

As you can see, the the `currentEnemy` variable needs to be passed down through 2 classes in order to get to where it needs to be: `BattleEventOne.Setup()`.

Furthermore, I needed to add the `Enemy currentEnemy` param to the parent `BattleEvent`, which is problematic because not all BattleEvents will need this information.

I originally wanted to just call `BattleSystem.currentEnemy` from `BattleEventOne` (using a property or something), but because the `BattleSystem` is abstract/static, it can't access it. And because `currentEnemy` contains new data each battle, I can't make that a static variable.

So, **how can I have `BattleEventOne` here access `BattleSystem.currentEnemy` without having to pass it down as I've done above?**

(I still struggle a lot with passing information between scripts, so any help here is really appreciated!)

Comment: I'm confused why you can't make `BattleSystem.currentEnemy` static.  At the beginning of each battle -- before setting up your battle events -- you are setting `currentEnemy` to the enemy for that battle right?  So unless you had multiple battles going simultaneously, I don't see the problem with making that static.

Comment: Oof, seems you're right. I actually considered that, but I was falsely under the impression that `static` variables couldn't - or at least should't - be changed once defined. I read online somewhere "Static variables are values where you only want one ever to exist", and took that to mean I shouldn't update it with new data. Thanks for taking the time to point this out.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Updating a `static` variable is fine.  The keyword `const` lets you declare a field and not allow it to be updated afterwards, but that has nothing to do with `static` (although they can be used together).

Comment: @BenRubin `static` actually cannot be used with `const` as the later always implies `static`. Perhaps you meant `readonly`; though with both `const` and `readonly` modifiers the identifier can only be set once their usage differs--`static readonly` is a read-only class variable but `const` is a compile time constant value and cannot be used with references.

Comment: In general be careful with `public void Start(Enemy enemyToLoad)` ... within a `MonoBehaviour` the parameterless message method [`Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) has a special meaning. You shouldn't use that name in Unity context as it will sooner or later cause confusions

Comment: @KevinBrock Yeah, you're right.  I meant `readonly`, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @derHugo, I see, is this because by having a `Start()` with parameters, I am "Method Overloading" the `Monobehavior` `Start()` function?